# Как работает стрелочная функция в JS

Tags: javascript

Вот есть код который выполняет отрисовку фреймов из спрайта. Но не понятен момент со стрелочной функцией. Мы создаем стрелочную функцию без параметров и вызывает методы. А затем в window.requestAnimationFrame(loop) мы передаем нашу стрелочную функцию, но как? Как мы смогли передать функцию когда не закончили ее тело цикла?

```
start() {
        let loop = () => {
            this.update();
            this.render();

            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
```

Comment: У вас нет тут цикла, loop это название функции что равноценно `let functionname = ()=>{} `

Comment: Ошибся, хотел написать тело функции. Поэтому и интересует вопрос как мы передаем функцию не закончив ее тело?

Comment: Так такое не только в стрелочных функциях, в обычных тоже самое, например [почитайте про рекурсию](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion)

Comment: А, вы имели ввиду как функция вызывается изнутри? Александр верно написал - рекурсия, есть много примеров

Answer (score 0):

Переменные вычисляются в момент выполнения функции просмотром области видимости. Поэтому подставив заранее имя какой-то переменной, мы не получим ошибку, пока функция не начнет выполняться.

```js
let loop = () => {
  print(someVariable);
}

//loop(); // приведет к ошибке т.к. не сможет найти print

let print = (param) => {
  console.log(param);
}

//loop(); // приведет к ошибке т.к. не сможет найти someVariable

someVariable = "ok";

// теперь все нормально, переменные будут вычислены тут и на этой точке они уже существуют.
loop();
```

То, что скрывается за переменной, функция или что-то еще, значения в данном случае не имеет.